# How to get unbuffered output from popen & fgets

Tags: linux, stream, popen, fgets, fcntl

I'm using `popen` to execute a command and read the output. I'm setting the file descriptor to non-blocking mode so that I can put in my own timeout, as follows:

```
    auto stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

    int fd = fileno(stream);
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);

    while(!feof(stream)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, MAX_BUF, stream) != NULL) {
            // do something with buffer...
        }
        sleep(10);
    }
    pclose(stream);
```

This works just fine, except that `fgets` keeps returning NULL, until the program has finished executing, at which time it returns all the output as expected.

In other words, even if the program immediately outputs some text **and a newline** to the stdout, my loop doesn't read it immediately; it only sees it later.

In the documentation for `popen` I see:

> Note that output popen() streams are block buffered by default.

I've tried a few things to turn off buffering (ex. `setvbuf(stream, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`) , but so far no luck.

How do I turn off buffering so that I can read the output in real-time?

Thank you!

Comment: By essence, fgets() returns only when it encounters EOF or end of line. So, if your program displays only one line (even a big one), fgets will not return before EOF or the first NEWLINE even if the underlying file descriptor has been set NONBLOCKING.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just edited the question to make clear that the first line being output by the sub-process includes a newline. Nevertheless, fgets doesn't read it for a while...

Comment: It is a race condition : the program calls fgets() before the command displays its first line. So, fgets() returns NULL the first time (if you display the errno when fgets() returns NULL, you will get EAGAIN). So, the main programs enters into sleep() before reading the first line.Meanwhile the command displays all its output. and the main programs gets everything after its sleep.

So, when I said above that fgets() will not return until it encounters "\n" or EOF, I was wrong. It returns with EAGAIN.

Comment: It's just sleeping for 10ms... It keeps calling fgets until EOF...

Comment: Yes, but display the errno before sleeping. You will get EAGAIN until the command finally begins to display its output.

By the way : sleep(10) = 10 seconds not 10 ms

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on something like select() would be more accurate and flexible. Try this :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/select.h>


    void read_cmd(const char *cmd)
    {
    FILE *stream;
    int fd;
    int flags;
    char buffer[1024];
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int rc;
    int eof;

      stream = popen(cmd, "r");

      fd = fileno(stream);

      eof = 0;
      while(!eof) {

        timeout.tv_sec = 10; // 10 seconds
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        FD_ZERO(&fdset);
        FD_SET(fd, &fdset);

        rc = select(fd + 1, &fdset, 0, 0, &timeout);

        switch(rc) {

          case -1: {
            // Error
            if (errno != EINTR) {
              fprintf(stderr, "select(): error '%m' (%d)\n", errno);
            }
            return;
          }
          break;

          case 0: {
            // Timeout
            printf("Timeout\n");
          }
          break;

          case 1: {
            // Something to read
            rc = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
            if (rc > 0) {
              buffer[rc] = '\0';
              printf("%s", buffer);
              fflush(stdout);
            }

            if (rc < 0) {
              fprintf(stderr, "read(): error '%m' (%d)\n", errno);
              eof = 1;
            }

            if (0 == rc) {
              // End of file
              eof = 1;
            }

          }
          break;

        } // End switch

      } // End while

      pclose(stream);

    }

    int main(int ac, char *av[])
    {

      read_cmd(av[1]);

      return 0;

    } // main
```